# Compositing output image shading

Tags: compositing-nodes, shaders

Is it possible to control the shading via a node in the compositor? I would like to generate two output images, one which has material shading and one without any shading - just the colors from the texture.

So far I only found how to control this option with the UI (of course) and with Python, but with these methods I have to render the image twice, which is somehow an overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cycles:

### Shadeless image:

You can do this in cycles by enabling the *Color passes* in *Renderlayers > Passes*:

[image]

Then add them together in the compositor with *Mix* nodes:

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Post composite:

[image]

### Shading only:

You can get only the shading of the render by dividing the full render and the color pass:

[image]

The reason the large cube appears as if it is still textured is that it has a *Glass* material, so that *is* the shading result. To prove this we can multiply it back with the color pass and we will get the full render again:

[image]

## Blender internal:

You could get a "shadeless" pass in BI with the *Color* pass in *Renderlayers > Passes*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

## Saving multiple images from the compositor:

You could then save the shadeless images in a separate directory with the [*File output*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Output#File_Output_Node) node:

[image]

Note that the output connected to the *composite output* node will be saved to the path specified *Render settings > Output*. In the absence of a *Composite*  node, the raw render will be saved.

The above node setup the raw render is saved to the path in *Render settings > Output* (in this case `/tmp/`) and the shadeless image is saved to `/tmp/shadeless/`.

Comment: But how do I get a "noiseless" rendered image?

Comment: or is it even possible in Blender Render?

Comment: @Masala What do you mean by a "noisless" image?

Comment: For example your original image. I have the same problem with my model. If I use Blender Render, the result looks much cleaner.

Comment: @Masala I added a way to do this with BI. To reduce noise in cycles you have to increase the number of samples in *Render settings > Sampling*. Note that this will increase the rendertime.

Comment: BI with a color pass works fine - thank you.