# Cycles Render without Shading (only texture and albedo)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, texture-baking

I have a Cycles scene with textures and diffuse materials. Now, I want to render images without any "shading." So, the pixel values of the images will be just the texture and diffuse value of the surface.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved this question by referring to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/compositing-output-image-shading)

Comment: @cegaton You closed the question just a second before I pressed *'Post Your Answer'* button. Damn! But you have a *Cycles* golden badge, so I won't argue. Respect!

Comment: @cegaton yes, please. After I post it you may close it again (since the OP found the right answer). I just want to post an answer I prepared.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show you two solutions:

- mix the *Transparent* and *Emission* shaders with the *Is Camera Ray* of the *Light Path* node as a factor
  [image]
- do the same as above but without *Transparent* node and uncheck the *Shadow* checkbox in the *Cycles Settings* panel of the *Object* header
  [image]