# Render without shading

Tags: rendering, shaders, shadeless

I am trying to render a scene without any shading.
I followed the steps shown in the answer of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/compositing-output-image-shading) question from many years ago:

1. Selected "Cycles" as render engine
2. Enabled color passes
   [image]
3. Added them in Compositor
   [image]

I am using 3 objects, with different materials:
-**Cube**: Principled BSDF from Image Texture
-**Sphere**: Principled BSDF (metallic)
-**Tree** (A model I downloaded from internet!): Principled BSDF from Image Texture

This is the final render
[image]

It worked correctly for the tree but not for the other two objetcs, also the world sky is not visible.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my blender file (with packed textures)
[image]

Comment: The passes you have enabled are only for objects in the scene - the background is not considered an object in the 3D space of the scene. To get it you have to enable the _Environment_ pass additonally to the ones you have. Apart from that, well how do the individual passes look before adding them together? Anything strange there? You could post screenshots of the separate outputs as well. Or even better, upload the file (with packed textures) here: https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question. Because creating something similar with my own stuff just works as expected...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just added my file

Comment: Looks just like expected when I render it: [shadeless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gsI.png), I'm sorry I cannot find any issue.

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: Blender 4.0.1, in my 3.6.5 it looks slightly different because in version 4.0 there were changes made to the _Principled BSDF_ shader especially regarding specularity, IOR etc., that's why the reflective parts add more brightness I guess: [shadeless 3.6.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWj6i.png). But still not like in your question. Comparison of the glossy color pass: [glossy 3.6.5 vs 4.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2phW.jpg)

Comment: I tried with blender 3.6.5 and it worked, I was using 3.1 before. I have no Idea why (since it works with even older versions), but thanks for solving my issue.